# how to pass variable in error

Tags: javascript, node.js

Heyo,

I have a following function

```
async function fnIsOnScreenOnce(img, desc,iCounter,client,repeatDelay=0) {
  await timeout(repeatDelay);
  let screenshot= await client.screenshot()

  let buf = new Buffer(screenshot.value, 'base64');
  let img1 = cv.imdecode(buf)
  let result = img1.matchTemplate(img, 5).minMaxLoc(); 
  result.screenshot=img1;
  if (result.maxVal <= 0.65) {
      // Fail
      const msg = "Can't see object yet";
      throw new Error(result);
  }
        // All good
        console.log("result:"+result)
        logger.info("Found image on screen: "+desc);
        return result;
}
```

Call of the function

```
function fnIsOnScreen(img,client, repeats = 5, desc, wait = 2000,repeatDelay) {
    logger.info("Looking for image on screen:" +desc +" with " + repeats + " repeats ");
    let iCounter = 0;
    let init = ()=> timeout(wait).then((asd)=>{
      const attempt = () => fnIsOnScreenOnce(img, desc, iCounter,client,repeatDelay).then((data=>{
        let imagepath=fnMarkOnImage(data.screenshot,img,data,outputDir)
        let description={};
        description.action="Is image on screen ?";
        description.desc=desc;
        description.repeats=repeats;
        description.wait=wait;
        description.img=imagepath;
        description.message="is this correct element ? if is then it was found correctly";
        fnPushToOutputArray(description)
      return data;
      })).catch(err => {
              console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
              console.log(err);
              console.log(err.result);
              iCounter++;
              if (iCounter === repeats) {
                  // Failed, out of retries
                  logger.info("Object not found : " + desc);
                  return Promise.reject("Object not found : " + desc);
              }
              // Retry after waiting
              return attempt();
          });
          return attempt();      
    })
    return init();


}
```

result object contains some date.
On error result contains {} object with no values in it. I would need to get all the values. So how can i pass result object through throw new error to retrieve it in catch ?

Comment: "on error" Why are you throwing an error? Why aren't you just returning that the value isn't high enough?

Comment: I am throwing an error because I repeat this function until it reachs its limit. I repeat it by calling it again in catch block. I check as well in catch block if it reached the limit. If it does i need to save result even if its erroneous one

Comment: Can you add the catch block

Comment: @Stamos you have it there

Comment: The `.catch` method you are using is designed to invoke upon the Promise Object's `reject` - ie. when the Promise is not resolved.  This is different than a standard try/catch.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One way to return extra data with error is to extend Error class and add them your self

```
class MyError extends Error {

    constructor(message, errorExtraParams) {
        super(message);
        this._errorExtraParams = errorExtraParams;
    }

    get errorExtraParams() {

        return this._errorExtraParams;

    }

}

throw new MyError("Error!!!", {})
//or
let mError =  new MyError("Error!!!", {})
console.log(mError.errorExtraParams)
```

But I suggest you don't use throw Error, because I don't like to throw Errors for insignificant reasons. What I mean is that in your case there is no reason to throw error cause there is no error and no reason to create an error just to tell you code "Hey I didnt find the image" instead just return false.

```
async function fnIsOnScreenOnce(img, desc, iCounter, client, repeatDelay = 0) {
    await timeout(repeatDelay);
    let screenshot = await client.screenshot()

    let buf = new Buffer(screenshot.value, 'base64');
    let img1 = cv.imdecode(buf)
    let result = img1.matchTemplate(img, 5).minMaxLoc();
    result.screenshot = img1;
    if (result.maxVal <= 0.65) {
        const msg = "Can't see object yet";
        return false;
    }
    // All good
    console.log("result:" + result)
    logger.info("Found image on screen: " + desc);
    return result;
}

function fnIsOnScreen(img, client, repeats = 5, desc, wait = 2000, repeatDelay) {
    logger.info("Looking for image on screen:" + desc + " with " + repeats + " repeats ");
    let iCounter = 0;
    let init = () => timeout(wait).then((asd) => {

        let found = false;
        do {
            let found = await fnIsOnScreenOnce(img, desc, iCounter, client, repeatDelay)
        } while (found !== false && iCounter++ < 10)

        let imagepath = fnMarkOnImage(found.screenshot, img, found, outputDir)

        let description = {};
        description.action = "Is image on screen ?";
        description.desc = desc;
        description.repeats = repeats;
        description.wait = wait;
        description.img = imagepath;
        description.message = "is this correct element ? if is then it was found correctly";
        fnPushToOutputArray(description)

        return found;

    })
    return init();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You should pass a String to the Error Object, so if you want to exchange an object you could use `JSON.stringify()` like this:

```js
try {
  throw new Error(JSON.stringify({result:"Hello, World"}));
}
catch(error) {
  console.log(JSON.parse(error.message))
}
```

As you can see, this is how you would send data from a try to a catch through throwing errors. You can ofc make the second part in the catch way shorter:

```
error = JSON.parse(error.message);
```

Comment: Yeah I was thinkin about this solution but its kinda dirty one :D Thx anway I ll mark if nobody else will come up with better one

Comment: you can access error massing by saying error.message :) no need to to cut it

Comment: and no need for the toString then ^^

Comment: sorry @Luca the guy under you got a correct solution

Answer (score 3):

You can try an approach like this

```
try {
   const err = new Error("My Error Occurred");
   err.extra ='Extra details';
   throw err;
}
catch (error) {
    console.log(error.extra)
}
```

As Error itself is an Object ,We can make use of this to pass extra variables  of our choice